# Dart Stream Data Length Check

Tags: flutter, dart

I have created following 2 streams.

Stream 1 - Periodic Stream which is calling an async function at a particular time.

Stream 2 - Function which listens on stream 1 and then create stream 2

I wanted to add logic such that if stream 1 length is more that 0 then only create stream 2. But I am getting length of stream 1 as always 0.

My Code is as follows. **(It runs after hot reload)**

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyPage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyPageState createState() => _MyPageState();
}

class _MyPageState extends State<MyPage> {
  StreamController<List<String>> _myStreamController =
      StreamController<List<String>>();
  int _counter = 0;

  Stream<List<String>> _stream() {
    Duration interval = Duration(milliseconds: 100);
    Stream<List<String>> stream =
        Stream<List<String>>.periodic(interval, temp2);

    return stream;
  }

  Future temp() async {
    List<String> a = [];
    _counter++;

    a.add(_counter.toString());
    return a;
  }

  List<String> temp2(int value) {
    List<String> _localMsg = List();
    temp().then((a) {
      print(a);
      _localMsg = a;
    });

    return _localMsg;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _stream().listen((ondata) {
      print(ondata);

      if (ondata.length > 0) _myStreamController.sink.add(ondata);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: StreamBuilder(
            stream: _myStreamController.stream,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.data != null) {
                return Text(snapshot.data.toString());
              } else {
                return Text("waiting...");
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: most likely you need `Stream.transform()` / `Stream.expand()`

Comment: I will explore that.